# Mixed precision assignment

Tags: fortran, double-precision

I am working with a large Fortran code that uses XLF compiler for Power7
It uses these flags to set the precision to 64bit: `-qrealsize=8 -qintsize=8`

However a recently imported piece of code has lines similar to this:

```
real :: var1d(nvol)
real :: var3d(ni,nj,nk)

var1d = var3d*1.0e6
```

I wonder how XLF is dealing with the literal `1e6`?
Main concern is; this is where a reference version and a modified version
deviate. The 9th and 10th significant figures are different for `var1d`.

Nastily this grows with iterations.

Comment: All real variables and constants should be promoted by the flag. I have no time to study the XLF manual, (you should do that!), but normal same compilers do that.

Comment: If I was concerned about this issue I'd probably rewrite the literal as `1.0d6` (or `1.0_real64` or some equivalent) and see what impact it has.  Of course, you'll probably tell me the deviations only begin after 100,000 cpu-hours of computation ....

Comment: To add to the other comments, `1e6` is a literal real constant of default kind.

Comment: for this particular example the `1.0E6`  is exactly represented regardless of its precision.  Of course you say "similar to this" so I guess you have some other cases where there is a difference.

Comment: Hi All,thanks for Vladimir reminding me to RTM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Data Object       REALSIZE(4) in Effect       REALSIZE(8) in Effect
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1.2               REAL(4)                      REAL(8)
1.2e0             REAL(4)                      REAL(8)
1.2d0             REAL(8)                      REAL(16)
1.2q0             REAL(16)                     REAL(16)

REAL              REAL(4)                      REAL(8)
DOUBLE PRECISION  REAL(8)                      REAL(16)
COMPLEX           COMPLEX(4)                   COMPLEX(8)
DOUBLE COMPLEX    COMPLEX(8)                   COMPLEX(16)
```

As stated in the on-line XLF manual. Thanks for all the useful suggestions. SO I will have to confirm this is not the source of discrepancy.